# log-rank test in R

Tags: r, survival, logrank-test

I need to use the `survdiff` function to statistically compare (using log-rank test) the following survival functions:
(1) Male (Sex=1) and Female (Sex=2)
(2) Patients <= 65 years-old and Patients > 65 years-old

I used the following command

```
Male <- survdiff(Surv(time,Status)~sex==1,data=myeloma)
Female <- survdiff(Surv(time,Status)~sex==2,data=myeloma)
```

is that correct ?

Comment: When you mention a function it's best to state which package it's from. Do you mean the `survdiff` function from `survival`?

Comment: library(survival)

Comment: yes I meant the survdiff function from survival package

Answer (score 8):

The examples provided in `?survdiff` are pretty clear. Using some example data included in `survival`, this

```
survdiff(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx,data=ovarian)
```

Is testing for a difference in survival between individuals with `rx = 1` and `rx = 2`. For your data, this will compare survival for males versus females

```
survdiff(Surv(time, Status) ~ sex, data=myeloma)
```

And this will compare survival for <= 65 versus >65.

```
survdiff(Surv(time, Status) ~ age, data=myeloma)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look right. If you want to limit the analysis to just males or females, the `sex==1` or `sex==2` is a separate input, the `subset` clause. The new commands would be

```
Males<-survdiff(surv(time,Status)~Patients, data = myeloma, sex==1)

Females<-survdiff(surv(time,Status)~Patients, data = myeloma, sex==2)
```

You need to specify *something* as the dependent variable in the equation, and the only remaing variable is Patients.

If you actually want to measure the effects of both sex and age together on survival, you need to be doing a *stratified* log rank test. I've used the function `SurvTest`(in documentation)/surv_test from the `coin` package.

As far as I could tell, it only takes one stratifying variable, but I came up with a workaround by appending several variables into a new variable and using that as the stratifying variable.

There are a couple of other packages that can do the same thing, but I can't think of them right now.

Comment: As the logrank test is a special case of the Cox proportional hazards model, it is unclear why you are using it.  And thinking of age > 65 as a point of discontinuity in  a (highly likely to be smooth) age effect does not make sense.  There is huge heterogeneity of age within the age > 65 group, and likewise for age <= 65.

Comment: To clarify that , my aim is to compare between both two gender in one comparison , and between age<=65 and age>65 separately. I need tow studies one between two gender and the other between two different groups of age

Comment: my data has these variable {time ,Status,age,sex}

Comment: SAMA, can you clarify your aim in your original post? The explanation you provided here is perfectly clear, and that is what you are missing in the original post.